# Connection refused on host.docker.internal

Tags: docker

I'm using,

- Docker Desktop For Mac 4.21.1 (114176)
- macOS Ventura 13.3.1
- Apple M2

I want to connect from a container to a service running on the host .

This is described in the docs here,

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

I start a webserver on the host listening on port 8000, then I do this,

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine sh
# apk add curl
# curl http://host.docker.internal:8000
```

It just doesn't work. I've been trying to figure this out for days. Any help would be much appreciated.

Are there some firewall rules that might be in place or something? I saw somewhere else that this might not even be possible on macOS?

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to resolve it in the end?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible. I read somewhere that it’s a security issue, which makes sense. Containers shouldn’t be allowed to do whatever they want with the host

Comment: I actually managed to fix it in the end - the issue was that my nodejs version inadvertently updated to 18 from 16 and this includes a change to by default bind to the ipv6 loopback address `[::1]` and docker for some reason does not support this. Explicitly making it bind to `0.0.0.0` fixed it for me. Hope it helps someone else